# R: Calculating the average of a subset of data

Tags: r, math, ggplot2

I have a big (for me anyway) dataset in long format of 2381 rows. It contains quarterly information, here's a sample:

```
Year    Price   Region
Q4 1973 7713    North
Q1 1974 7743    North
Q2 1974 7733    North
Q3 1974 7862    North
Q4 1974 7932    North
Q1 1975 8151    North
.
.
.
Q1 2015 188566  UK
Q2 2015 194258  UK
Q3 2015 195733  UK
Q4 2015 197044  UK
Q1 2016 198564  UK
```

I want to calculate the yearly mean for each region and then plot it using ggplot2. I'm ok with the plotting, but I'm struggling to find how to automate getting the average for so many different years (there are 13 regions in total).

Any help?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105670/how-to-calculate-average-values-large-datasets) which shows three methods for getting averages by a date-time constraint

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want a single mean price for each year, or the mean for each Region for each year.  If the former, you can do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

meanPrice <- dt %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(meanPrice = mean(Price))
ggplot(meanPrice, aes(x = Year, y = meanPrice)) + geom_line()
```

If it's the latter, then you can do this:

```
meanPrice2 <- dt %>% group_by(Region, Year) %>% summarise(meanPrice = mean(Price))
ggplot(meanPrice2, aes(x = Year, y = meanPrice, colour = Region)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Hey, this appears to have worked, but when I'm plotting my graph the data appears four times! See image added above. This may warrant another question, but what's going on there?

Comment: Not sure, I can't tell from this, but I have a feeling the problem might be with the Year variable, which wouldn't normally have that many tick marks.  Have you checked its class?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data are stored in a data frame named `df`. Here is what you can do in order to get the average `Price` per `Year`:

```
aggregate(Price ~ Year, df, mean)
```

In case you want the average per `Year` per `Region`:

```
aggregate(Price ~ Year + Region, df, mean)
```